# what is wrong with this rsync command?

Tags: ssh, rsync

Is this syntax wrong for `rsync` command? The target server is using port `2222` as ssh port but I can't define it right in the `rsync` command.

```
rsync -dr /home/88/public_html/download/ali -e ssh ssh -p 2222 root@44.44.44.44:/home/44/public_html -v
```

Comment: Missing quotes : -e "ssh 'ssh -p 2222'" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549945/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-different-ssh-port-when-using-rsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222' -dr /home/88/public_html/download/ali root@44.44.44.44:/home/44/public_html -v
```

The `-e` option allows you to specify the remote shell AND all options that go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try below syntax

```
rsync -e "ssh -p 2222" -avz  --exclude-from '/root/scripts/kexlude.txt' /home/88/public_html/download/ali/ root@44.44.44.44:/home/44/public_html/
```

--exclude-from is optional if you want skip any files in synchronization, you can put file/folder path in /root/scripts/kexlude.txt.(one per line)

also you add **--dry-run** in syntax to test sync output without doing actual transfer.